# How to create new a new db entry only if certain values in the db do not already exist but some do?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask app that takes in user details and stores to PostgreSQL DB. The table in the DB has columns, email, location, and visits.

What I am trying to achieve:

- If a user email is not in DB create new user entry.
- If the user email exists and the location is the same, increment visits counter by 1.
- If the user email exists but the location is different create new
  user entry

Email is got through an HTML form and if passed on submit. Location is passed to the view via the URL(https://myapp.com/location.

Then end result will have duplicate email addresses in the DB if the user has visited different locations so can tell how many times that user has visited each location.

I have tried every possible way I can think all but all just create a new entry every time.

**routes.py**

```
if form.terms_and_conditions.data is not False:
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        customer = Client.query.filter_by
                   (email=form.email.data.lower()).first()
            if customer is None:
                full_client = Client(email=form.email.data.lower(), 
                                     location=location)
                db.session.add(full_client)
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('get_success'))
            elif customer.location != location:
                full_client = Client(email=form.email.data.lower(), 
                                     location=location)
                db.session.add(full_client)
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('get_success'))
            elif customer.location == location:
                customer.visits = customer.visits + 1
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('get_success'))
        else:
            flash("Please enter a vaild E-mail address")
    else:
        flash("You must agree to the terms and conditions ")
        return redirect(url_for('get_click', sitename=location))
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(db.Model):

    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = (db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, nullable=False))
    location = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True)
    visits = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}>'.format(self.email)
```

Comment: From where you get "location" in "elif customer.location != **location:**", I guess it should be "form.location.data", right?

Comment: If still not working after using the correct "location" variable, then I suspect that something wrong in **"Client.query.filter_by
                   (email=form.email.data.lower()).first()"**. Try to change it to something like : **db.session.query(Client).filter(Client.email==form.email.data)**